# How to select a value from dropdown to show results in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coming to an issue, where I have a drop-down list of items showing, and when you select an item it won't show a table based on the selected item. I have a search input with autocomplete - that works, but I can't get the drop-down to work. Does anyone know how to solve this issue with jquery or just vanilla javascript? thanks for the help.

**here is my code**

```
      <select class="selectMenuSize" >
    <option value="">select</option>
    <c:forEach items="#{mybean.jobSearchItems}" var="searchItem">
      <option value="#{searchItem.getSearchValue()}" id="searchInputField" name="searchInput">#{searchItem.toString()}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
```

**jquery**

```
     $(function () {
 var myData = [];
              $.get("http://localhost:8080/myApp/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        myData.push({
                            id: v.id,
                            label: v.label,
                            value: v.id,

                        });
                    });
                });

                   $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: myData

                });


                $('#searchForm').submit(function () {

                    $('#results').text($(this).serialize());
                    return true;
                });


           });







            function handleSubmit(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                let url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
                let searchValue = document.getElementById('searchTextField').value;
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
                fetch(url, {body: data, method: "post"})
                        .then(res => res.text())
                        .then(text => {
                            let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
                            console.log(doc);
                            document.getElementById("results").appendChild(doc.body.firstElementChild);
                        });

           document.getElementById('searchForm').onsubmit = handleSubmit;


            }
```

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything with the dropdown. Nowhere in your code are you doing anything with the values or checking what item is selected. You are with your search input and that's why that works.

Comment: the drop down values are populated with jsf tags. I need some help to get me started on the dropdown selection in jquery

Comment: is it going to be the same as my autocomplete?